react tiptap Editor disable markdown rendering
I am using the tiptap editor in my application, where I am displaying markdown and a custom extension.
When the user is editing die content, the markdown elements should not be "rendered", but instead the markdown syntax should be displayed.
I changed the enablePasteRules and enableInputRules to false, so when the user is typing or pasting, the markdown does not get "rendered".
But on initialization, when setting the content, the markdown still gets rendered.
Handling paste and input:
const editor = useEditor({
    ...
    enablePasteRules: false,
    enableInputRules: false,
    extensions: [
        StarterKit,
        MarkdownExtension,
        ...
    ],
    ...
})

Initialization on opening the editor
useEffect(() => {
    if (editor) {
        editor.commands.setContent(props.value)
    }
}, [editor])

The passed string from props.value is correct (logged it) but the Markdown gets rendered, which should only happen in preview mode.
If i copy and paste the logged props.value, it also works fine.
Hope anyone can help me, because it drives me crazy...

Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, including clear details on the specific issue and exact reproduction steps.
